# Wordpress white screen

Tags: migration, fatal-error

I have big problem with white screen in WordPress.

I would like to migrate site from live to localhost, I don't have credentials for hosting, and I've migrated site using All In One Import Plugin.

**Steps:**

1. I've extracted `.wpress` file using `wpress-extractor`.
2. On Localhost installed fresh WordPress
3. Created new database and imported database from live site
4. Files from extracted `.wpress` file I've copied into `wp-content`
5. Inside `wp-config.php` change database, set credentials for login, change prefix of database etc ...
6. After that I've run `Interconnect/it` script to change paths inside Database
7. Finally when I visit site I've got **white screen** , If I try to login I've got login inputs, but when click on submit button I see white screen.

**What I tried:**

1. Deleting all plugins
2. Deleting theme
3. `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true )`
4. `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');`
5. Tried to run in incognito mode of Chrome
6. Deleted `.htaccess`

and still same problem ...

Can someone help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i can give you solution but without it's without any plugins or .wpress files...

1) copy all the content from your server directory to localhost/anyfolder_name directory.
2) create database in phpmyadmin and import the database from your server's phpmyadmin ..

3) once imported in localhost phpmyadmin open wp_options in that change site and website URL to your localhost URL.

4) delete .htacess file ..

5) open directly localhost/your anyfolder name /wp=login.php

6) login with credentials and go to permalinks and just click save button.

and you will see the same website in your localhost ..

7) if you use any antivirus or security plugin for your server wordpress like wordfence then rename the pluginn name and some other pluginn files which are present in wordpress directory.....

Comment: if still problem persist then activate WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php

Comment: and send me a error log...

Comment: if it worked then upvote me ...

Comment: Like I've said I don't have credentials for hosting, only from dashboard administration.

Comment: try to open .wpress file with winrar and copy files from it ...

Comment: have you tried to open .wpress file in WINRAR....

Comment: upvote my answer please..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend All in One WP Migration : https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ to copy a site from live to local.

Just install plugin on live and export
Then install fresh WP on local, install plugin and import

I do all site transfers this way